# Removed mongodb document with the same fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a scheduler running on my server and generating a list of medications that didn't sign every day, this problem occurs sometimes and while solving this issue I want to create a script checking and deleting those duplicate items generated. Appreciate your help.

**Here some sample date generated** : I want to check matched field [med, time, date] and return only 1 document then removed all duplicates.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea026a0b4e0015d80f77"),
    "med": ObjectId("610845e7f5b0e00017754d50"),
    "Time": "8:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea026a0b4e0015d80fd4"),
    "med": ObjectId("61f988e82cf5760018113cee"),
    "Time": "7:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea026a0b4e0015d80fdd"),
    "med": ObjectId("62d1c6e93603ed00177812ee"),
    "Time": "6:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea02304a870015dfa2ec"),
    "med": ObjectId("610845e7f5b0e00017754d50"),
    "Time": "8:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.005+0000"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea02304a870015dfa349"),
    "med": ObjectId("61f988e82cf5760018113cee"),
    "Time": "7:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.005+0000"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6375ea02304a870015dfa352"),
    "med": ObjectId("62d1c6e93603ed00177812ee"),
    "Time": "6:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.005+0000"
  }
]
```

**Expected output**: (Note: Time and Date are different)

```
[
  {
    "med": ObjectId("610845e7f5b0e00017754d50"),
    "Time": "8:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
  {
    "med": ObjectId("61f988e82cf5760018113cee"),
    "Time": "7:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
  {
    "med": ObjectId("62d1c6e93603ed00177812ee"),
    "Time": "6:00am",
    "Date": "2022-11-16T08:00:00.008+0000"
  },
]
```

Here Mongodb Playground for displaying result -> [Mongodb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cMJixokZCOP)

Comment: Why is `"Time"` different than the time in `"Date"`?  Is there any risk of removing legitimate "simultaneous double doses" by removing "duplicates"?

Comment: Why would you store the time separately than the date and in a non ISO format? Also, it is not clear what your question actually is - what are you trying to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The "Time" and "Date" was different, the date added was scheduled by the generated script while the "Time" specific value for the med

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answer will helpful

Note:- Your date is not same in every object so may be your expected output is  wrong

i have attached playground url with code.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYrgPd7od02

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        med: "$med",
        Time: "$Time",
        Date: "$Date",
        
      },
      "med": {
        "$first": "$med"
      },
      "Time": {
        "$first": "$Time"
      },
      "Date": {
        "$first": "Date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Developer, I parsed the date so I can get my expected output
 "Date": { "$dateFromString": { dateString: "$date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } }

Comment: This solved my question and [here updated answer](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jak5BQYmEkB)

Comment: @Jezzy In your mongoplayground.net, your `"_id.Date"` in `"$group"` will be `null` for every document.  I doubt that's what you want.